# What to use to read/write from dynamodb from Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to know what's the best to use to read/write from dynamodb from Spark.

I've tried with the official API from dynamodb, also with the emr connector(hadoop and also with hive) and others.

But i've found (among other problems) that to perform a query a full scan is needed, and that's not something valid with big tables.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

The process you tried using `emr-dynamodb-connector` is generally the way most of the people use it.

However there is a [library](https://github.com/traviscrawford/spark-dynamodb) which you could use to connect to DynamoDb.

Generally accessing DynamoDb from spark is difficult because now you have tied spark executors with the DynamoDb throttle. One alternative you could try is to use `Hbase` or `cassandra` which I found better supported with spark usage, provides predicate pushdown etc.

Generally the way I use DynamoDB data on cluster with spark is by utilizing the DynamoDb stream. Collect the stream data in S3 and apply batch processing on that data.

Comment: Thanks, I guess i'll have to keep trying or switch to something different. 
I also tried that library but it only allow reads and has limitations (it doesnt work boolean types for example)